# Cannot get jQuery to recognize mouse hover over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I am trying to animate a picture when the mouse cursor hovers over it. I am using jQuery to accomplish this. I cannot figure out why it does not work for the current state of my code. Apologies in advance, I just started my endeavour into web development.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="CSS/stylesheet_test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/animate.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:500&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/test.js"></script>
    <title>Daryl N.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="nav-text"><span id="home"><a href="index_test.html">Home</a></span><span id="archive">Archive</span></div>
      </div>
      <div id="first" class="background">
        <div class="align-vert"><img id="me-pic" src="./images/me.jpg" alt="A picture of me is suppose to be here" style="width:240px;height:240px;" class="me-border animated bounceIn"><span class="daryl animated bounceIn">Hi, I'm Daryl</span></div>
      </div>
      <div id="second" class="background">
        <p class="align-vert">This is my personal website</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    if($('#me-pic').is(':hover')
    {
        alert("Hello");
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

The source of my problem came from setting the z-index of my image div to -1. Changing this solved my problem, as well as changing the script.

Comment: Don't bind a mousemove event to the entire page. Its extremely inefficient. Think about how many times that method is going to run. There is a way to make the method you have chosen work by using the event args from mousemove, but it would require comparison of attributes. Use the `$(selector).hover()` method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if your method should work or not, but there's a better way to handle this, designed for the original purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#me-pic').hover(function() {
    alert("Hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: That still does not work. Could something in my CSS file cause problems?

Comment: Try to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, since you seem to be loading the js file above the rest of the page, this will cause it to wait for the page to finish loading. Edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can attach the hover event directly onto the selector, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#me-pic').hover(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    })
});
```

Comment: That still does not work. Could something in my CSS file cause problems?

Comment: Not likely, what errors are you getting in the console?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `hover` jquery method.

```
$('#me-pic').hover(function(){
    alert("Hello");
})
```

View reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Further more,I recommend you remove `$(document).mousemove()` event.In this situation, it is inefficient method.